# Tomcat Service - CATALINA_TMPDIR

Tags: tomcat

I'm currently using the below command to have Tomcat run as a service

(Navigate to Tomcat/bin folder)

```
"tomcat8.exe" //DS//Tomcat_JJP_TRAIN
"service.bat" install Tomcat_JJP_TRAIN
"tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_JJP_TRAIN  --JvmMs=1024 --JvmMx=2048     --JavaHome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111" ++JvmOptions="-Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

And it works good. My question is regarding the CATALINA_TMPDIR... I want to set that variable to either %temp% or c:\windows\temp

Since it is running as a service, I can't do it by editing the catalina.bat file. And I don't want to (and not sure if even possible) set it via the "Tomcat config gui applet". Also, I'm already using a -D parameter to set the timezone, but I don't believe I can make what I want by setting the -Djava.io.tmpdir parameter... at least I tried it and it didn't work.

Can someone advise on how I can point my Tomcat service to use the temp folder I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable `CATALINA_TMPDIR` is only useful for when you use the scripts to launch Tomcat. If you read the scripts, you'll see this in the command to launch the JVM:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%"
```

So, all you have to do is set the `java.io.tmpdir` system property when you create the service. Just change your `//US//` command to this:

```
"tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_JJP_TRAIN  --JvmMs=1024 --JvmMx=2048     --JavaHome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111" ++JvmOptions="-Duser.timezone=UTC;-Djava.io.tmpdir=/your/preferred/path"
```